# How to take a screen shot in Android 2.3.5 ZTE tablet?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread

Please tell me how to take a screen shot in reliance ZTE 2.3.5 android tablet?

Comment: Is the device rooted? I'm afraid with Android versions before 4.x this is a requirement for a screenshot app to work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simultaneously pressing the power button & volume down an holding? If that doesn't work try with home + volume down combination. If zte has not provided a shortcut, just use a digital camera or another phone camera to take a snapshot of the screen.

Advanced: If your phone is rooted some apps will help you take screenshot. A cumbersome way would be to turn on the developer mode in your tablet and use adb.exe that is part of the android sdk after connecting your phone to the usb port in your PC.